# Subir automáticamente a la base el usuario de un formulario

Tags: laravel

La base de datos tiene el campo *usuario*. ¿Cómo hacer que al grabar un formulario, se grabe el usuario de la persona que se registró?

```html
 <div class="form-group" type="hidden">
    {{ Form::label('user_id') }}
    {{ Form::text('user_id', $cliente->user_id, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('user_id') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'User Id']) }}
    {!! $errors->first('user_id', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
 </div>
```

Comment: Buen día, no es muy claro lo que deseas hacer, ¿Quieres obtener el `id` del usuario que tiene su sesión activa?

Comment: Hola lo que quiero es llenar un formulario de un cliente y cuando se guarde la información en la base de datos guarde también el usuario que grabó el cliente

Comment: Entonces no es "la persona que se registró", sino "la persona que registró al cliente". Es una pequeña gran diferencia. Pulsa en [edit] para corregir el enunciado, y por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por último: ¡no olvides que los signos de puntuación _existen_!

Comment: Hola es la persona que se logueo y registro el cliente en el formulario cliente